# Openshift error 503 with sparkjava

Tags: openshift, spark-java

I am trying to create a simple web page using openshift platform and sparkjava which would redirect me to a static html file (index.html) place in the folder 'src/main/resources/public'. I have created the application using the below command, but when I navigate to the location "http://appname-domainname.rhcloud.com, the page gives below error

**Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.**

command used for creating the app:

```
rhc app create appname --from-code=github repository url
```

Java code used for the routing is as below:

```
public class AppStart {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String IP_ADDRESS = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP");
        int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT"));

        setIpAddress(IP_ADDRESS);
        setPort(PORT);
        staticFileLocation("/public");

        get("/",new Route(){
             public Object handle(Request request, Response response) {

                 response.redirect("index.html");
                return "";

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue finally solved. The problem was:

start, stop and deploy scripts were not properly implemented.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @Gavin: I guess this is the answer to self

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some tests on it recently, Sparkjava is amazing for building REST/Single Page Web apps. But I need more information to help you. Is your program handling requests to resources (I mean, those rest ones, not static resources)? What would happen if you add the following line to your program and try to access http://appname-domainname.rhcloud.com/help ?

```
// Needs import static spark.Spark.*;

get("/help", (req, resp) -> "How may I help you?");
```